# Taylor series to approximate derivative with difference quotient function

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion, approximation-theory, numerical-calculus

Consider the following example on Taylor series.

Let's consider the difference quotient function of center $x_0$:
$$f'_h(x_0)=\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$
For $h$ sufficiently small, the difference quotient function approximates the derivative:
$$f'_h(x_0)=\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}\approx f'(x_0)$$
Now my textbook says:

> We want to evaluate how $f'_h(x_0)$ approaches $f'(x_0)$. Let's use Taylor's Theorem, with $n=1,x=x_0+h$ in order to represent $f(x_0+h)$:
>   $$f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+hf'(x_0)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(\xi_h)$$
>   so
>   $$f'_h(x_0)=\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=\\\frac{f(x_0)+hf'(x_0)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(\xi_h)-f(x_0)}{h}=\\f'(x_0)+\frac{h}{2}f''(\xi_h)$$

I understand all the steps but it's not clear to me why that's done this way, especially:

> ...with $n=1,x=x_0+h$ in order to represent $f(x_0+h)$...

For context, the textbook is about Numerical Calculus and the paragraph is an introduction to discretization errors.

Could you help me clarify why each step of the above procedure was done?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by all the steps. The Taylor formula gives an **exact** representation of $f(x_0+h)$ and so one can use this to express $f_h'(x_0)$ in terms of $f'(x_0)$ and other terms.

Comment: I think the author is simply saying $x=x_0+h$, $n=1$ because is a linear Taylor expansion  of $f(x)$ around $x_0$, where $h=x-x_0=\Delta x$

Answer (score 0):

We are considering the first order expansion ($n=1$) for Taylor's series with Lagrange remainder around the point $x_0$ ($x=x_0+h$) that is indeed

$$f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+hf'(x_0)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(\xi_h)$$

Refer also to the related

- [Taylor series Lagrange Remainder explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1775210/505767)