# Geometry of Lagrange error formula using the generalized mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

From what I understand, the mean value theorem appears in the error between $f\left(x\right)$ and a constant approximation of $T_0$:

$$\left| f\left(x\right) - \ T_0 \left(x\right)\right| =  \ \left| f\left(x\right) - \ f\left(a\right) \right| =  \left| \frac{f\left(x\right) - \ f\left(a\right)}{x-a} \cdot\ \left(x-a\right) \right| = \left| f'\left(c_0\right) \cdot\ \left(x-a\right) \right|$$

And here $f'\left(c_0\right)$ is that value of $x$ that satisfies the MVT... but how does this generalize to higher derivatives? (or at least the next polynomial $T_1$)

Using $e^x$, I figured out the error with $T_1$ could be found with $c_1$ but I'm losing the geometry of what's going on.

---

I found this: [Taylor series Lagrange Remainder explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775210/taylor-series-lagrange-remainder-explanation)

Comment: I assume that you meant $f'(c_0)$.

Comment: There's no geometry involved.